# error on pagebreak in index of makeindex when using center environment in footer of package scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: header-footer, page-breaking, indexing, makeindex, scrlayer-scrpage

I run into strange compilation errors regarding the combination of packages `scrlayer-scrpage` and `makeidx`. I reduced this to the following case

- Define a footer via `\cfoot*` that contains a `center` environment
- Produce index entries such that a page break occurs.

If I remove the footer, or do not use `center` in it, everything seems fine. Same goes for having any index not longer than a page. This also does not seem to depend on `\footheight`, the error occurs independ of the height.

The packages do not mention each other, so I have no idea where to search for a solution.

As a workaround, I know that I could use e.g. `\hfill` in the footer to achieve the same effect as `center`, but I would rather like to understand why above error occurs and fix it properly.

Just in case this is relevant: In my actual use case, I use `imakeidx` with a custom index name and document class `scrartcl`, but as testing has shown so far, the error seems to be independent of these.

See the MWE below for the occuring error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\cfoot*
  {
    \begin{center}
      Something in footer
    \end{center}
  }

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
foo

\index{}
\index{b1}
\index{b2}
\index{b3}
\index{b4}
\index{b5}
\index{b6}
\index{b7}
\index{b8}
\index{b9}
\index{b10}
\index{b11}
\index{b12}
\index{b13}
\index{b14}
\index{b15}
\index{b16}
\index{b17}
\index{b18}
\index{b19}
\index{b20}
\index{b21}
\index{b22}
\index{b23}
\index{b24}
\index{b25}
\index{b26}
\index{b27}
\index{b28}
\index{b29}
\index{b30}
\index{b31}
\index{b32}
\index{b33}
\index{b34}
\index{b35}
\index{b36}
\index{b37}
\index{b38}
\index{b39}
\index{b40}
\index{b41}
\index{b42}
\index{b43}
\index{b44}
\index{b45}
\index{b46}
\index{b47}
\index{b48}
\index{b49}
\index{b50}
\index{b51}
\index{b52}
\index{b53}
\index{b54}
\index{b55}
\index{b56}
\index{b57}
\index{b58}
\index{b59}
\index{b60}
\index{a1}
\index{a2}
\index{a3}
\index{a4}
\index{a5}
\index{a6}
\index{a7}
\index{a8}
\index{a9}
\index{a10}
\index{a11}
\index{a12}
\index{a13}
\index{a14}
\index{a15}
\index{a16}
\index{a17}
\index{a18}
\index{a19}
\index{a20}
\index{a21}
\index{a22}
\index{a23}
\index{a24}
\index{a25}
\index{a26}
\index{a27}
\index{a28}
\index{a29}
\index{a30}
\index{a31}
\index{a32}
\index{a33}
\index{a34}
\index{a35}
\index{a36}
\index{a37}
\index{a38}
\index{a39}
\index{a40}
\index{a41}
\index{a42}
\index{a43}
\index{a44}
\index{a45}
\index{a46}
\index{a47}
\index{a48}
\index{a49}
\index{a50}
\index{a51}
\index{a52}
\index{a53}
\index{a54}
\index{a55}
\index{a56}
\index{a57}
\index{a58}
\index{a59}
\index{a60}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: it doesn't make sense to use center inside a footer.

Comment: Oh, you are right. Somehow I wasn't aware that footers are already centered.